# set up virtual environment as interpreter in PyCharm but the module can not be used

Tags: python, pycharm

I clone a python project from github and a virtual environment has been set up in the project.

Then I set up this virtual environment in the python interpretor and module "urllib3" is shown in the package list.

However when I run the project, the error occurs

> No module named 'urllib3'

It seems that the virtual environment does not take effects but I am really confused why.

Plus, I run this program in terminal by

```
pytest xxx.py
```

I am not sure whether this is a reason for the problem.
If it is, how to fix it?

Comment: if you see a 'venv' folder in your repo, I suggest deleting it and recreating your own. This is because the folder includes a link to the local disk python executable, which will not be found on your disk.

Comment: well I tried the original project and it works all fine when I uses run in Pycharm instead of command in terminal.
I am not sure whether this problem is caused because I run the program in the terminal.

Comment: nope, your running program in the terminal won't affect its virtualenv. do you mind posting the link to the repo?

Comment: sorry but this is a private project...

Comment: it's ok, I've added an answer. Hope that helps : )

Answer (score 0):

The most practical solution I can propose to this problem is to recreate a virtual environment of your own. Since you mentioned you could run the program in Terminal, first activate the cloned environment.

On Linux or Mac:

```sh
source venv/bin/activate
```

On Windows:

```sh
source venv/Scripts/activate
```

Then once it's activated, get the list of packages:

```sh
pip freeze > requirements.txt
deactivate
```

Remove cloned environment:

```sh
rm -rf venv
```

Recreate a new one:

```sh
python -m venv venv
source venv\bin\activate (Or Scripts if on Windows)
pip install -r requirements.txt
```